# How to speed up reading and writing binary file operation in python?

Tags: python, django, performance, opencv, read-write

I have got a binary file(400MB) that I first want to read and then write to another file in python.Currently what I'm doing is very basic.

```
file = 'file.bin'
with open('temp','wb+') as dest:
    for chunk in file.chunks():
        dest.write(chunk)
```

This code is a part of my Django app that I want to speed up.Is there any other better way to speed up this operation?

**Update:**
Alright,to make things a bit more clear what I'm trying to do is loading an in-memory video file(binary data) in OpenCV using cv2.VideoCapture(filename) which I think is not possible as of now.So now I have to read the file from memory and write it to disk so that OpenCV operation can be performed.Basically I'm trying to get the video duration for validation purposes.

```
    import cv2
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(dest.name)
    fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)  
    frame_count = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    duration = frame_count/fps
```

Comment: Your question is extremely vague and broad. IO performance has many factors many of which are bound to the hardware and operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it after suffering for hours.But if you are a newbie programmer I guess you can't escape it. I was trying to get the path of the request.FILES in my Django view so that I can use it in OpenCV VideoCapture. So this is how I did it.

```
file = request.FILES['filename'].file   
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file.name)
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) 
frame_count = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
duration = frame_count/fps
```

**Update June/2020** This method will only work if your file size is more than 2.5 Mb.For files less than 2.5Mb you need to add this to your settings.py file.

```
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = [
    'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler',
]
```